# List all images from a single post meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, images, post-meta

I have created a custom post type with an image gallery upload. Now I am trying to display the gallery on the front end. This is what I have so far that works to display 1 image, but if multiple images are uploaded all the URLs get stuck in the `src` tag. So I'm guessing I should loop through that array and spit out each one separately? Would that be the route to go and if so how can I accomplish this?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
echo '<img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery-upload', true).'">';    
?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT:

This is what I ended up with that works...

```
<?php
foreach(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery-upload') as $meta) {
 foreach(explode(',', $meta) as $src) {
  echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($src).'">';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you give an example of what WordPress prints out when you have more than one photo?

Comment: Check out my edit above

Answer (score 2):

You should reorganize the way you store the images: Make the uploaded files children of that particular post, do not put them in a post meta field. Then get all the images with [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). Look at the built-in handler for the `[gallery]` shortcode for some examples.

I should go like this:

```
$args = array( 
   'post_mime_type' => 'image',
   'numberposts'    => -1,
   'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
   'post_type'      => 'attachment' 
);

$attached_images = get_children( $args );

foreach ( $attached_images as $image )
{
    // print image
}
```

And even if you want to stay with post meta fields, do not store URLs, use the attachment IDs instead. URLs can change any time (think about a migration from dev to production site).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll need to do some research. I used this tutorial here: http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2012/01/image-uploads-on-wordpress-admin-screens-using-jquery-and-new-plupload/#prettyPhoto which is using Javascript to store the URL's.

Comment: I noticed that it is being stored under "uploads" folder. So shouldn't this transfer over ok from development to it being live? I do agree that your answer looks like a better way, but I am unable to find how to rewrite how the JS is storing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm guessing I should loop through that array and spit out each one separately? Would that be the route to go and if so how can I accomplish this?

Yes. `get_post_meta(...)` should return an array without that last parameter, or with it set to false. You'd then have...

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery-upload');
foreach ($meta as $m) {
    echo '<img src="'.$m.'">'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it produced the same results I had before. For some reason it isn't reproducing the img tags, it just spits all the data out in img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Get images from Gallery Custom Post Meta

```
  <?php 
    $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery');
    foreach ($meta as $m) :
    $img_atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $m, $default );
    $img_src = $img_atts[0];
  ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="<?php echo $img_src ?>" alt=""></div>

  <?php endforeach ?>
```